# Loss function for regression

Tags: regression, self-study, joint-distribution

I am studying [Christopher's Bishop](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/%7Ewurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf) book on "pattern recognition and machine learning". I have come across the regression loss function before, usually it is expressed as $$\sum_{i=1}^N \{t_i - y(x_i)\}^2$$

where $t_i$ represents the true value, $y(x_i)$ represents the function to approximate $t_i$.

In the book however, the regression loss is written in the form
$$E[L] = \int \int L(t,y(x))p(x,t)dx \,dt$$

The expectation is taken with respect to samples from the joint distribution of $p(x,t)$. How do we go about thinking about the joint distribution of $p(x,t)$ ?

How do we actually compute the joint distribution for $p(x,t)$ in the regression sense. For classification, the Naive Bayes algorithm can be used to compute the distribution for $p(x,C)$ where $C \in \{C_1, C_2, ..., C_k\}$ classes from the data itself by combining the likelihood and the prior. Hence, $p(x,C_i)$ for classification is just a scalar value.

Comment: The first equation is an empirical version of the second: divided by $N$ it converges to its expectation.

Comment: Besides the points already mentioned, using naive Bayes to calculate joint distribution is a bad idea. This algorithm works pretty well in many scenarios for classification tasks, but it does not give good approximations of probabilities in most cases.

Comment: @Tim What do you mean by works very well but does not give good approximations ?

Comment: @calveeen that it does good job in some tasks, e.g. spam filtering, but does not give reliable estimates for the probabilities as it assumes that all the features are independent, what would never be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the first comment, the first version is one to evaluate empirically on given data, whereas the second one with $E[L]$ is a theoretical population version for a general loss function $L$; in the first equation $L(t,y(x))=(t-y(x))^2$, but the second one can use other loss functions if desired (which will then have empirical versions as well, summing up other losses).

The given formula for $E[L]$ assumes both $x$ and $t$ to be random (sometimes in regression modeling $x$ is assumed to be fixed, but it's probably not worthwhile to go into this because it doesn't make that much of a difference for the question). Regarding the distribution $p(x,t)$, obviously for evaluating the theoretical $E[L]$ one needs to make some model assumptions about it, however in empirical data the best that we have is the empirical distribution of the $t$ and the $x$. Now if we evaluate the integral in $E[L]$ with $p$ being the empirical distribution of $(x,t)$ on a given dataset of size $N$ (i.e., every observed $(x_i,t_i)$ appears with probability $\frac{1}{N}$), it is actually $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^NL(t_i,y(x_i))$, and with the squared loss $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N(t_i-y(x_i))^2$ (if we consider $N$ as fixed, the factor $\frac{1}{N}$ is just a constant that doesn't matter). This connects the two formulae. (When making model assumptions about $p$ in order to say something theoretical about $E[L]$, one would hope that they are more or less in line with the empirical distribution of a dataset to which theoretical results are applied.)

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful